# Is there a design reason why std::set doesnt have front and back member functions?

Tags: c++, set, api-design, member-functions, design-decisions

1. I know I can use `*s.begin()`, but same argument can be used for `vector`, which has `front`/`back`
2. often I use the ordered property of set/map to get "smallest" element/key - ofc the fact that **I** do it is not the reason to have it, just a example :)

Here I'm talking about *design* reasons why `front`/`back` would be bad design, so please skip obvious reasons like committee forgot about it...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I imagine that the words "front" and "back" are reserved for *sequence* containers (i.e. those where the order of elements is determined by the order of insertion), and the words are meant to suggest a physical position in that sequence.

Since `set` is not a sequence container (but instead an associative container), this isn't appropriate. In particular, note that the meaning of "front" can change by later insertions of an unrelated element.

Comment: The second paragraph doesn't really make sense; the `back` of a `vector` can change too, by a `push_back`. But +1 for the first paragraph.

Comment: @larsmans: Yes, "back" can change if you change the back. But you'll be explicitly changing the back. In a set, it would be an *unrelated* change, if you see what I mean. This explanation works best when you think about a list.

Comment: (If you will, `std::list` is the star example, and `std::vector` has the exception that insertions invalidate "back", and `std::deque` has the exception that insertions in the middle invalidate both "front" and "back". Those statements are actually true on the nose for references.)

Comment: Of course, references need not be invalidated by unrelated updates (if I recall correctly that B-trees cannot be used for `std::set` because of invalidation issues), they just wouldn't point to the front or back any more.

Comment: @larsmans: Indeed, in the standard library, all *node-based* containers retain full iterator and reference validity during arbitrary insertions and deletions.

Comment: Maybe it would make sense for these associative containers to have `first`/`last` (they would imply "... according to the provided or defaulted `Compare`"); or maybe `min`/`max`, despite the latter naming would be very confusing when the ordering predicate is chosen to be `std::greater`-like.

Comment: If it's not meant to be a sequence, explain why we have `begin`/`end`.