# How to find closest vowel?

Tags: c++

I wrote a program that lets the user input a character. If the character is a vowel, do nothing; if the character is a consonant, find the closest vowel in the alphabet. Is there any easy way to do this?

Here's what I have for now:

```
char input, output;
cin >> input;
if (input == 'b'){ output = 'a'; }
else if (input == 'c'){ output = 'a'; }
else if (input == 'd'){ output = 'e'; }
else if (input == 'f'){ output = 'e'; }
else if (input == 'g'){ output = 'e'; }
else if (input == 'h'){ output = 'i'; }
else if (input == 'j'){ output = 'i'; }
else if (input == 'k'){ output = 'i'; }
else if (input == 'l'){ output = 'i'; }
else if (input == 'm'){ output = 'o'; }
else if (input == 'n'){ output = 'o'; }
else if (input == 'p'){ output = 'o'; }
else if (input == 'q'){ output = 'o'; }
else if (input == 'r'){ output = 'o'; }
else if (input == 's'){ output = 'u'; }
else if (input == 't'){ output = 'u'; }
else if (input == 'v'){ output = 'u'; }
else if (input == 'w'){ output = 'u'; }
else if (input == 'x'){ output = 'u'; }
else if (input == 'y'){ output = 'u'; }
else if (input == 'z'){ output = 'u'; }
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: You can keep an array of vowels and scan it for each character read.  Not sure whether it will be simpler.

Comment: @PM77-1 That would be the same thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could also use an array:

```
const char nearestVowels[26] = "aaaeeeeiiiiioooooouuuuuyyy";
                             // abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Then you could simply do this:

```
output = nearestVowels[input - 'a'];
```

Comment: By far the most beautiful solution!

Comment: Yes! This is the best solution!

Comment: It does cause Undefined Behavior if you enter `B` though. Or `3`. Or `!`.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want something like this:

```
if (input != 'a' && input != 'e' && input != 'i' && input != 'o' && input != 'u')
{
    if ('a' <= input && input <= 'c')   { output = 'a'; }
    else if (input <= 'g')              { output = 'e'; }
    else if (input <= 'l')              { output = 'i'; }
    else if (input <= 'r')              { output = 'o'; }
    else if (input <= 'z')              { output = 'u'; }
}
```

[<kbd>Live On Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dcba0a25feaa0c3)

Answer (score 4):

It can be done like this too:

```
if(input>='a'&&input<='z'){
if(input<='c')output='a';
else if(input<='g')output='e';
else if(input<='l')output='i';
else if(input<='r')output='o';
else if(input<='z')output='u';
}
```

The first `if` makes sure that no input other than a~z are fed into output.

Answer (score 2):

There are very many ways to do this, perhaps the most concise (albeit ugly) is:

```
const char* p = strchr(input, "bacadefegehijikilimonopoqorosutuvuwuxuyuzu");
output = (p && *p) ? p[1] : input;
```

This works by seeking a `char*` to `input` in that string literal, then if found it returns the following character.  It won't crash for any character code 0-255, but if you input a vowel it will find it in the string and return the following consonant - if that's a problem, it's probably better to use the following...

Have two arrays - one of consonants and another of vowels, and if you find `input` in the former get the vowel from the same index in the latter.

Yet another way is to use a `std::map`:

```
std::map<char, char> m { { 'b', 'a' }, {'c', 'a' } etc... };
if (auto i = m.find(input))
    output = *i;
else
    output = input;
```

`switch` is a bit more verbose than the above, but will likely give the fastest performance (but do measure if you care).

Answer (score 1):

`switch` would be simpler:

```
switch (input)
{
    case 'b':
    case 'c':
        output = 'a';
        break;
    case 'd':
    case 'f':
    case 'g':
        output = 'e';
        break;
    ...
    etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c69eb2d13f7c1c65) feels more generic:

1. Get the ASCII value of the input
2. Substract each vowels's ASCII value as its distance and store (vowel, distance) in a list
3. Sort the list
4. Get its first pair's key (the vowel)

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std; 

bool compare(const pair<char, int>& a, const pair<char, int>& b)
{
    return a.second < b.second;
}

int main()
{
    char vowels[] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    char input;
    //std::cin >> input;
    input = 'r';
    vector<pair<char, int>> distances;
    for (char& vowel : vowels)
    {
        distances.push_back(make_pair(vowel, abs(input - vowel)));
    }
    sort(distances.begin(), distances.end(), compare);
    pair<char, int> nearest = distances.front();
    if (nearest.second > 0)
    {
        cout << nearest.first;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `map<int, char>` instead. That gives you `distances[abs(input-vowel)] = vowel` after which you can return `distance.front()`. Lot less code.

Comment: @MSalters `std::map` does not offer a `front()` method. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16981600/344480

Comment: Eh, right, `*begin()` then. Still a silly omission from the STL. Also, you'd get a `pair<int,char>` (compared you your code which has the pair reversed)

Comment: @MSalters Referring to the SO answers, "begin() implies lets start somewhere, no matter where". I don't think that the order is guaranteed. Anyway, I wanted to provide an understandable implementation without any over-optimized code. Disclaimer: I'm a Java developer.

Comment: The order is not guaranteed in general. For the 3 basic containers, it's insertion order, for the two ordered containers it's obviously the container order, it's just the two unordered containers who have no guarantee whatsoever. As `std::map` is one of the ordered containers, `*begin()` is the smallest. Also, in C++ `list` generally is not a recommended class (prefer `vector`).

Comment: @MSalters I updated my answer to `vector` which is faster in sorting. Still I wouldn't like a `std::map` implementation since I had to use the distance rather than the vowel itself as it's key. Anyway, thanks for your comments. I learned some things!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one I made in Java, it's not assigned statically and supports lower and upper case letters.

```
public static char closestVowel(char character) {
    int value = (int) character;
    if(character == 'z' || character == 'Z')
        return (char) (value - 25);
    if(isVowel(character)) {
        return character;
    } else {
        return closestVowel((char) (value - 1));
    }
}

public static boolean isVowel(char character) {
    return "aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(character) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful! Except it's not in c++... Thanks anyways, since I can take out the concept.